# AssemblyVersion vs AssemblyFileVersion in .Net Framework 4.0

Tags: .net, vb.net

There are number of threads about this topic but none of them cover this case if we're building an EXE application and no DLLs, I was increasing both values with the same value for each new build, and found that "Make single instance application" options is not working for different version builds!
So I've been told to keep major/minor of AssemblyFileVersion the same!

Now, when dealing with EXE app without Strong Signing, is it wise to keep the AssemblyVersion as 1.0.0.0 ALWAYS, and only increase AssemblyFileVersion for each build?
Any issues might occur?
Thanks for thoughts.

Comment: I think the real question is if you are building new a new app, why are you not migrating to a newer version of .NET? You really ought to migrate before you start a new app.

Comment: AssemblyVersion is what .NET uses for resolution (matching the reference against the provided file).  AssemblyFileVersion is what goes into the Windows file version resource.  I would recommend to *only* update the AssemblyVersion when you intend to communicate an upgrade that may invalidate existing references.

Comment: What is the purpose of your single instance application? Only to prevent it being started a second time or to start it a second time in the same process? In the first case, you can manually achieve this through a Mutex. If the application may only be started once on the whole machine, use a "Global\" one (if user A runs it, user B cannot start it), if it may be started once in each terminal session (if user A runs it, user B can still start it), us a "Local\" one. If any version of your application cannot run together, omit the version in the mutex's name, otherwise include it.